# Good practice to allocate new session ID on each request?

Tags: java, session-cookies, sessionid

A customer has requested some security enhancements to our Java web application, including the following:

> According to our security team good security practices state that
>   session id should be changed on every request to prevent session
>   hijacking.

I understand the importance of allocating a new session ID upon authentication (which we already do), but this request seems a bit extreme.

If reallocating on a per-request basis, it sounds like it's no longer a session ID, but rather a single-use request ID that might be used in conjunction with a session ID.

So, my question: is such a tactic really a common security practice? If so, could somebody point me to a good discussion on the topic, implementation tips, etc.?

Comment: New session ID on each requests? Sounds like no sessions more.

Comment: What if the hijackers hijack the response. Now they have the new session id and the real user is locked out. I think the customers brains trust security team need to rethink their request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't hurt, but it can be really complicated and really you only need to re-generate the session id when the security level changes. See also [Session Hijacking - regenerate session ID on Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1246/session-hijacking-regenerate-session-id).

Answer (score 1):

Generating a new session ID for each request does not make any sense and it flies in the face of the concept of a session.  However, including a request ID with all requests which will cause a state change (for example, form submission) is a very sensible idea.

The intent of a per/request ID is to prevent CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery).  See: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: +1 agreed. A new session every request is moronic, because it means effectively you don't have a session! Better to have no session id and go stateless!